# Add rows to a table for each ID from a result-set

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

Consider the result-set

```
SELECT UNIQUE order_id FROM order_details WHERE date=2011-01-01
```

(The PK is order_id and item_id together.)

For each order_id in this result-set, I want to append a gift (which has an item_id = 1000027) to that id  - meaning I want to add an additional row in the order_details table for each order_id from this result_set (since each order from that day gets a gift). I will 'hardcode' 1000027 for each inserted row.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? SQL Server supports SELECT DISTINCT but not SELECT UNIQUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.  Please note I am making some assumptions on your columns.  I have no idea what other columns exist in the table however I'm pretty sure that order_id, item_id and date are required.

```
INSERT INTO order_details (order_id, item_id, date)
SELECT UNIQUE
  order_id,
  1000027,
  getDate()
FROM order_details 
WHERE date = '01/01/2011'
  AND item_id <> 1000027
```

Comment: Probably need to add `AND item_id <> 1000027` to avoid a PK constraint violation.